# How to choose an hashing algorithm

Tags: hash, cryptography

I'm writing a web service. And, accordingly, when registering a user, I need to hash passwords. The question is, which algorithm is better to use? As I understand the most persistent can be considered argon2,bcrypt,blowfish. What is your opinion? I would be grateful for articles with comparison

Comment: I have always been told bcrypt because of its slowness, and I have always used bcrypt myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argon2, BCrypt, SCrypt and PBKDF2 are appropriate algorithms, all of them can control the necessary time to calculate the password-hash.

Blowfish on the other hand is an encryption algorithm (two-way) and should not be used for storing passwords, probably you mixed it up with BCrypt which is based upon blowfish.